# how to prevent accessing a hidden field using the Quick Edit

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, list, development

I have a field named "Item number" inside my Issue tracking list, which is a system generated ID, and i do not want end users to be able to modify it . now i have set this column as "Hidden" inside the content type to hide it when Create or edit items.

But i am displaying it inside the "All Items" view, which caused a problem, because end users are be able to edit this system generated ID using the Quick Edit capability, as follow:-

[image]

so can anyone adivce how to prevent modifying a column using the quick edit capability ?,for example by disabling the related cells  ??

**EDIT:-**

now when i access the site column from my "site setting >> site columns" i got the following URL :-

```
http://..../_layouts/15/fldedit.aspx?field=ID1&Source=%2F%5Flayouts%2F15%2Fmngfield%2Easpx%3FFilter%3DAll%2520Groups
```

as follow:-

[image]

which means the item id = ID1 is this correct ? based on this i wrote the following `HideColumnsINGrid.js` script :-

```
(function () {
    var overrideContext = {};
    overrideContext.Templates = overrideContext.Templates || {};
    overrideContext.Templates.OnPreRender = function(ctx) {
        var statusField = ctx.ListSchema.Field.filter(function(f) {
            return f.ID === 'ID1';
        });
        if (statusField) {
            statusField[0].AllowGridEditing = false;
        }
    }
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(overrideContext);
})();
```

then i wrote the following powershell script to define the jslink insdie the column :-

```
 $web = Get-SPWeb http://vstg01
    $field = $web.Fields["Item Number"]
    $field.JSLink = "Style%20Library/JS/HideColumnsINGrid.js"
    $field.Update($true

)
```

the power-shell script worked well, but still i i can edit the item named "Item Number" from the quick edit . i have a feeling that the item id and name i specified is not correct

Answer (score 1):

Is is possible and quite easy to disable field in quick edit mode using client side rendering (a.k.a CSR or JSLink). Here is the sample of doing this http://chuvash.eu/2014/11/28/disabling-a-column-in-quick-edit/

Comment: thanks a lot of the link,, now seems i can  hide this  <<in the OnPreRender event in our Client Side Rendering (CSR) registration.>> But i am not sure how/where i need to add the script ? is it inside the master page ?

Comment: can i use web part to add or referecne the script ?

Comment: Try to specify JSLink property in web part properties

Comment: can you adivce more on this ?where i need to add the web part ? to the master page ? and what type of web part i need to add ?

Comment: http://zimmergren.net/technical/sp-2013-using-the-spfield-jslink-property-to-change-the-way-your-field-is-rendered-in-sharepoint-2013 look here how to specify JsLink property

Comment: ok then can i edit the column xml using SharePoint designer ? so i can define its  JSLINK as follow "JSLink="/_layouts/15/Zimmergren.JSLinkSample/Awesomeness.js" " ??

Comment: You can assign your JsLink link directly to the web part, without any SharePoint Designer, as showed in the section "Set the JS Link property on a List View Web Part"

Comment: ok i got your point , but now i have 4+ lists and each list have around 3+ list views, where each list view have a Quick Edit ability. so in this case i need to modify the 12 web parts and add a reference to the script. and let say in the future i need to add a new list view, then i have to reference the script again.. so i want to have a more appropriate approach of having this apply at once ,, did u get my point ?

Comment: You can specify JSLINK property for the site column and will work on all lists and view's in site collection. You can specify JsLink property using PowerShell

Comment: ok great so i will write the following power shell script "$web = Get-SPWeb http://tozit-sp:2015
$field = $web.Fields["Priority"]
$field.JSLink = "/_layouts/15/MyCustomScript.js"
$field.Update($true)". but what i need to include inside the custom script ? should i write a script such as the one inside this link http://chuvash.eu/2014/11/28/disabling-a-column-in-quick-edit/

Comment: also inside the jslink i need to write the following "$field = $web.Fields["Priority"]" so does Priority represents the display name of the field ?

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: can you check my edit section to the original question,, i tried the scripts but did not work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24641/discussion-between-ecm4d-and-john-g).

Comment: i tried adding the script to the _layout folder but nothing happened

Answer (score 0):

I believe JQuery & Browser Developer Tools are your options. There might be certain classes/attributes added to the column containing this field in EDIT mode. Just check it.

As per the screenshot, you can blindly get the Column 2 of the editable table & then make it display none or Add a MASK (transparent) around it.

Like in edit mode I found the text that we are editing sits inside a SPAN with class "jsgrid-control-text". So you can say below

1. Get the SPAN element in SECOND column of each ROW in this table & then add a onChange event handler to it where you say return FALSE
2. Or using the same above logic hide the COLUMN 2 completely.

You can trigger the above JS function on click of EDIT button. (For which you have to attach a click handler to EDIT button in JQuery.Ready() in your Master page Javascript.

This may not solve or may not be appropriate, but we can get the job done.

Comment: but you are saying that i will always hide the second column, then what if we changed the order of the column inside the view ,, then this will not work !!

Comment: you can handle this by looping through all the columns & then find the right one using its attributes & then get the SPAN inside it. Check the below links for custom getting elements with custom attributes matches  1. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13392463/jquery-select-all-element-with-custom-attribute, 2. https://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/

Answer (score 0):

If the "Item Number" column is not the built-in ID column, you can just create a calculated column with a formula of `=[Item Number]` and display that column in your All Items view instead of the actual "Item Number" column. (Depending on how the Item Number is generated by your system, you may have to modify that process slightly to force it to trigger the calculated column's update.) Calculated columns can't be edited in Quick Edit.

If the "Item Number" column *is* the built-in ID column, it gets a little trickier, because SharePoint will error out when it tries to run the calculation on new items before the ID is generated. In this case, you'll need a more complex approach, with two additional columns and a workflow. For this explanation, I'll use `ID` to refer to the built-in column.

First, create a text column `getID` (and make it hidden) and a calculated column `showID` with the formula `=IF(ISBLANK(getID),"",getID)`

Then create a workflow set to run on new item creation and manual activation (so you can run it on all your existing items):

```
If [Current Item:getID] is empty
  Set [Current Item:getID] to [Current Item:ID]
```

Finally, in your All Items view, display the `showID` column instead of the `ID` column, and run the workflow on all of your existing list items.